# Vim making a lot of processes in mac

Tags: java, macos, vim

I am using vim to code in java on my mac. I started using vim and out of a sudden, my mac became really slow. I opened up activity monitor and saw this:
[ScreenShot of my situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoeaY.png)

So for a short-term solution, I have found that `killall java` works.
But I don't understand why that happens and how to fix it.

List of my vim plugins:

- nerd tree
- lightline.vim
- ale
- vim-javacomplete2
- ultisnips
- vaxe
- vim-maven-plugin
- tlib_vim
- vim-addon-mw-utils
- vim-snippets
- YouCompleteMe

This is a really big problem for me and I don't have a clue how to fix it.
Thanks, RaitoDaku!

Comment: Are you sure it is vim? try starting vim with `vim -u NONE` is it solved?
If so start binary searching your plugins (deactivate half of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of those plugins, ALE is a likely culprit. By default, it continuously runs the configured linters in the background, on every change to the buffer inside Vim. As you've been editing Java files, and most Java linters are written in Java themselves, that's a likely explanation.

You should try dialing down how often ALE is triggered; they even have [a FAQ entry](https://github.com/w0rp/ale#faq-my-battery-is-sad) for that common complaint.

#### Bonus: Generic troubleshooting tips

- You can capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for suspect commands. In case of launched processes, these would be `:!` and `:call system()`.
- Often, a *binary search* where you disable half of your plugins, then only one half of that (when the problem is still there), or the other half (when the problem vanished) lets you get to the problematic script quickly. If you use a package manager or the now built-in *pack plugins*, the disabling is really simple. The same can be done with the configuration in your `~/.vimrc` (by commenting out blocks).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am going to delete it right now. Is there any alternative for that plugin that would eat as much memory?

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with ALE, except that its default configuration assumes a powerful machine. You can keep the checking, just dial it down (either to be manually triggered or just on `CursorHold`), or disable that particular linter, and it should be fine.